# Implementations of Interfaces in Java

Tags: java, interface

I have a program assignment for school that converts temperatures from degrees Fahrenheit to degrees Celsius using interface. I guess my question is do I put the code in the interface or in the actual class?

I have talked to my professor and he was not much help. Not looking for any code just what to know where I should put my code.

```
package program5;
public class program5 implements Interface2
{

   public void Temperature_Convertor()
   {
    //Implementation of Temperature_Converter();

   }

   public void Temperature_Print()
   {
    //Implementation of Temperature_Print();
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {

   }
}
```

Now for my two interfaces

First one,

```
package program5;
public interface Interface1 
{
   public static void Temperature_Convertor()
   {

   }
}
```

And the Second one

```
package program5;
public interface Interface2 extends Interface1 
{
  public static void Temperature_Print()
  {

  }
}
```

Again not looking for any code, just wondering where to put it. Thanks again!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Interfaces can't have method bodies.

Comment: @cricket_007, in java 8, interfaces can have static method bodies

Comment: @HankD Hmm, guess I learned something today. I don't see the use-case of a interface static method for this question, though.

Comment: If you declare methods in an interface, and implement them in a class, neither one should be declared "static".  In your interfaces, your methods are static, but your implementation methods in the class are not, which is a problem. You should remove the static from the interface methods, and that will answer your question for you--the compiler won't let your non-static interface methods have a body, and you will be forced to put the logic in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces describe a type of behavior your implementing class (`program5`) will perform.  The actual work should be done in `program5` - the comments in your assignment (where it says "//Implementation") even say to do it there.

Answer (score 0):

In your interfaces, do this -

Your `Temperature_Converter` method needs 1 value (temperature in F) to work on, and produces one result (temperature in C). So change it to this -

```
public interface Interface2 {
    public double Temperature_Converter(double tempInF);
}
```

Similarly, the `Temperature_Print` method needs a single value to print -

```
public interface Interface1 {
    public void Temperature_Print(double temp);
}
```

Now, your main program (`program5`) needs to perform both these tasks (convert and print), so it must implement both the interfaces -

```
public class program5 implements Interface1, Interface2 {

    public double Temperature_Converter(double tempInF) {
        double tempInC = .....;        // Your implementation
        return tempInC;
    }

    public void Temperature_Print(double temp) {
        .....        // Your implementation
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Interfaces define what you want to do, not how to do it.

Take a look at this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).

PS: Just as a note, methods' name should begin with lower case letter.